# handle check event on checkbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, wpf-controls

I've a listview containing name and two checkboxes( name, male(checkbox),female(checkbox)). I want make sure only one checkbox is selected from listview at a time.

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="datatemp">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding VmName}" Width="129" Visibility="Visible" />
            <CheckBox  Name="cb"  IsThreeState="False" Checked="off_chek_select"  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="6,0,18,6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <CheckBox  Name="cb1" IsThreeState="False" Checked="ins_chek_select" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

here, I've used this **datatemplate** in listview. I'm not able to access controls from datatemplate for writing on check event.

Answer (score 0):

Into `Tag` property you can put reference to parent element (in your case it's `StackPanel`) and in code-behind you can find element by using `FindName` method.

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="datatemp">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding VmName}" Width="129" Visibility="Visible" />
        <CheckBox  Name="cb" Tag="{Binding ElementName=stackPanel}"  IsThreeState="False" Checked="off_chek_select"  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="6,0,18,6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <CheckBox  Name="cb1" Tag="{Binding ElementName=stackPanel}" IsThreeState="False" Checked="ins_chek_select" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void off_chek_select(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cbSender = sender as CheckBox;
    if (cbSender != null)
    {
        var stackPanel = cbSender.Tag as StackPanel;
        if (stackPanel != null)
        {
            var cb1 = stackPanel.FindName("cb1") as CheckBox;
            if (cb1 != null)
            {
                cb1.IsChecked = !cbSender.IsChecked;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ins_chek_select(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cbSender = sender as CheckBox;
    if (cbSender != null)
    {
        var stackPanel = cbSender.Tag as StackPanel;
        if (stackPanel != null)
        {
            var cb = stackPanel.FindName("cb") as CheckBox;
            if (cb != null)
            {
                cb.IsChecked = !cbSender.IsChecked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have multiple choices and only one should be selected at the time you could use RadioButton ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="datatemp">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding VmName}" Width="129" Visibility="Visible" />
            <RadioButton  Name="cb"  IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="6,0,18,6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <RadioButton  Name="cb1" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: actually it is an example of what i am trying to do. I dont want to use radiobuttons. Is there anyway to do it with Chekboxes

Comment: @AbhishekNehe check my answer again :)

Comment: i cant access the second checkbox on click event of first checkbox. i want to implement same functionality like radioboxes but using  checkboxes.

Comment: @AbhishekNehe check my answer again :)